# git merge without commiting

Tags: git

I am currently trying to merge 2 branches using *git*.

When I `git merge branch`, it automatically merges and tries to commit, requiring me to write the commit message in a file named `MERGE_MSG`.

However, this is not the behaviour I desire. I want to manually type in the command `git commit -m "merging branch into ..."` and not have any file being opened for me.

I have also set these:

```
merge.commit=no
merge.ff=no
```

extra question: Can I somehow have git auto-sign my commits so I do not have to use the flag everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag to pass to `git merge` to have it not commit is called `--no-commit` ([ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-commit)). It will do the merge, but stop just short of committing, which you can then do yourself.

```
git merge --no-commit branch
```

To always have `git commit` sign your commits, set `commit.gpgsign` to `true` ([ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitgpgSign)).

```
git config commit.gpgsign true
```

A good place for these kinds of questions is the reference documentation:

- [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)
- [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)